# Select specific field inside a list from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection with records in this format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "UNKNOWN",
      "ID": "UNKNOWN",
      "payload": {
        "value": -56,
        "unit": "dBm"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "UNKNOWN",
      "ID": "UNKNOWN",
      "payload": {
        "value": -10,
        "unit": "dBm"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now is it possible to get only data[1].payload.value instead of returning the entire record?

Comment: This Documentation Source May helpful: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only

Comment: I tried slice, but its not helpful to get the specific field